# Finding sum of data frame column in rows that contain certain value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I'm working on a March Madness project.  I have a data frame `df.A` with every team and season.
For example:

```
Season   Team Name   Code
  2003   Creighton   2003-1166
  2003   Notre Dame  2003-1323
  2003   Arizona     2003-1112
```

And another data frame `df.B` with game results of of every game every season:

```
WTeamScore  LTeamScore  WTeamCode  LTeamCode
15          10          2003-1166  2003-1323
20          15          2003-1323  2003-1112
10          5           2003-1112  2003-1166
```

I'm trying to get a column in `df.A` that totals the number of points in both wins and losses.  Basically:

```
Season   Team Name   Code        Points
  2003   Creighton   2003-1166   20
  2003   Notre Dame  2003-1323   30
  2003   Arizona     2003-1112   25
```

There are obviously thousands more rows in each data frame, but this is the general idea.  What would be the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option using `tidyverse`, where we can pivot `df.B` to long form, then get the sum for each team, then join back to `df.A`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df.B %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(),names_pattern = "(WTeam|LTeam)(.*)",
               names_to = c("rep", ".value")) %>% 
  group_by(Code) %>% 
  summarise(Points = sum(Score)) %>% 
  left_join(df.A, ., by = "Code")
```

**Output**

```
  Season  Team.Name      Code Points
1   2003  Creighton 2003-1166     20
2   2003 Notre Dame 2003-1323     30
3   2003    Arizona 2003-1112     25
```

**Data**

```
df.A <- structure(list(Season = c(2003L, 2003L, 2003L), Team.Name = c("Creighton", 
"Notre Dame", "Arizona"), Code = c("2003-1166", "2003-1323", 
"2003-1112")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df.B <- structure(list(WTeamScore = c(15L, 20L, 10L), LTeamScore = c(10L, 
15L, 5L), WTeamCode = c("2003-1166", "2003-1323", "2003-1112"
), LTeamCode = c("2003-1323", "2003-1112", "2003-1166")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `match` (from `base R`) between 'Code' on 'df.A' to 'WTeamCode', 'LTeamCode' in df.B to get the matching index, to extract the corresponding 'Score' columns and get the sum (`+`)

```
df.A$Points <- with(df.A, df.B$WTeamScore[match(Code, 
       df.B$WTeamCode)] + 
       df.B$LTeamScore[match(Code, df.B$LTeamCode)])
```

-output

```
> df.A
  Season   TeamName      Code Points
1   2003  Creighton 2003-1166     20
2   2003 Notre Dame 2003-1323     30
3   2003    Arizona 2003-1112     25
```

---

If there are nonmatches resulting in missing values (`NA`) from `match`, `cbind` the vectors to create a `matrix` and use `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
df.A$Points <- with(df.A, rowSums(cbind(df.B$WTeamScore[match(Code, 
   df.B$WTeamCode)],  
     df.B$LTeamScore[match(Code, df.B$LTeamCode)]), na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df.A <- structure(list(Season = c(2003L, 2003L, 2003L), TeamName = c("Creighton", 
"Notre Dame", "Arizona"), Code = c("2003-1166", "2003-1323", 
"2003-1112")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df.B <- structure(list(WTeamScore = c(15L, 20L, 10L), LTeamScore = c(10L, 
15L, 5L), WTeamCode = c("2003-1166", "2003-1323", "2003-1112"
), LTeamCode = c("2003-1323", "2003-1112", "2003-1166")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```